# Mongodb/python Count different rows containing different values

Tags: python, mongodb, distinct

Here is my problem :

I have a mongodb database with +1 million entries and I have to count distinct entries.

Every entry has a doc_id composed of the communication number and the document number, here is an example : EGNG9876543219876543219-000.pdf

The part composed of 4 capital letters and 19 digits is the communication number.

The thing is that for each communication number there are multiple documents (the "-000.pdf part).

I tried to do it this way :

```
docIds=list(collection.find({}, {"doc_id" : 1,"_id":0}))
comIds=[]
for i in range (docIds.count("doc_id")):
    comIds.append(docIds[i][:-8])
print(len(set(comIds)))
```

I would like to know if there is a way in mongodb to count how many distinct communication numbers there are.

Comment: It will be good if you can share what you have tried

Comment: I added my code :)